# How to detect screen's DPI change in Qt?

Tags: qt, dpi

Since I have a window (derived from `QWidget`) which may switch between two monitors and dynamically update according to screen DPI, it seems that I can only listen to `screenChanged(QScreen*)` signal. It works fine when I drag the window between monitors.

But it doesn't work when I open app in another monitor and switches menu bar between two monitors (through System Preference -> Displays -> Arrangement in mac). It seems that the signal is not emitted in that situation.

Which signal should I listen to? Is there a better way?

Comment: If you application is switched to abother monitor, when you switch menu bar, then it is a bug in Qt. You may create a bugreport: https://bugreports.qt.io